# Changing Cell Color in Excel

Tags: excel, colors

I am trying to make cells change color when it is within 30 days (yellow) or Past Due Date (Red) of a specified date. Is this possible? This to help provide a visual reminder of which reports will be due and which reports are overdue.

I have tried making it change from current date but the dates vary based on when the services was started

Comment: What do you mean by "when the services was started" Don't you want to simply calculate every time the file is opened?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a straightforward use of the Conditional Formatting feature in Excel. In the Conditional Formatting dropdown (should be on your main toolbar) you can add a New Rule and select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". You can create multiple rules that will be applied to test each condition (e.g. overdue, within 30 days, etc). This is the best answer I can give without seeing the structure of the data